# Very applied question: How does an ANOVA compare two regression models?

Tags: regression, anova

I think I understood ANOVA in general but I try to understand how programs like R implement an ANOVA to compare regression models. Or respectively how an ANOVA does that.

Let's say we have a polynomial of a 2nd order and a polynomial of a 3rd order. How is an ANOVA comparing them and providing the corresponding result?

It isn't just plain telling "Yes, there is a significance between them", or is it? If so, is it possible to compare each arbitrary models with each other?

Comment: You can only compare nested models via SS and F-tests, otherwise you can compare them using something like AIC.

Comment: At first thanks but I'm not sure how understand your statement. For example, I can fit a model with a 2nd polynomial and again with a 3rd polynomial. In R I can compare them via "anova(lm2nd, lm3rd) which provides some results (e.g. AIC, BIC).

Comment: Yes, you can do that. So where is the issue? Are you asking how the differences in the models are compared? If so, there should be plenty of answers on this site (it's based on SS and F-tests).

Comment: Thanks, this was already a helpful statement! A final question: Anova will "only" make a statement about whether there is a significance, or not. Right? Nothing else?

Comment: When testing two nested linear models you will get an F-test result on the two models. So an F statistic, degrees of freedom, SS and a p-value. So yes, a statement of whether the two models are statistically significantly different.

Comment: how is "nested" meant here? Is pol(2) nested in pol(3)? what about testing e^x against 1/x ?

Comment: A nested model is one which is entirely contained in another model, so for ex. `lm(y~x)` is entirely contained in `lm(y~x+z)`. Your case of `e^x` and `1/x` are not nested.

Comment: This means e^x and 1/x cannot tested via an anova? Just to ensure.

Comment: Not with SS and F-test. Something like AIC / BIC, ...

Comment: anova() provides AIC and BIC values?

Comment: Usually no, you have to use `AIC()` or `logLik()`.